# Program has returned control to the operating system in 8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

When i run my assembly program it returns:
`Program has returned control to the operating system`
in Assembly 8086
I want it to make a logical expressions of `and` logic.
Here is my code :

```
org 100h

mov al,45h 
mov bl ,67h 

AND al,bl 

ret
```

Comment: Your program did the calculations and exited.

Comment: You already did do that; single-step it with the debugger built-in to emu8086 to see the values in registers change when the AND runs.

Answer (score 2):

Your program **made** a logical expression `45h AND 67h` and put the result `45h` into register `al`.  What you probably want is to **display** the result. You can use DOS function [WRITE CHARACTER TO STANDARD OUTPUT](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm). This service expects a character in register `DL`, so copy the result of your logical expression to `DL`, set `AH` to 2 and invoke the DOS interrupt `INT 21h`. This should print the character with ASCII value `45h` which happens to appear as the letter **E**.
Later you may want to convert the binary result to hexadecimal form **45h**, or to binary form **01000101b**. Search this site to find out how.